# Minimum pumping length of concatenation of two languages

Tags: regular-languages, pumping-lemma

there's this small part of my homework that I just can't figure out.

Let us denote $p(L)$ as the minimum pumping length of some language $L$. I'm supposed to find two regular languages $A,B$ so that

$$
p(AB)=p(A)+p(B)
$$

But whatever I try, I can only find languages so that

$$
p(AB) < p(A)+p(B)
$$

I've been sitting at this the whole day and I'm just going in circles. Can someone please give me a hint?

Comment: Can you double check what you are supposed to prove? It looks like we can prove $p(AB)\le p(A)+p(B)-1$. That is, $p(AB)=p(A)+p(B)$ does not hold in any case.

Comment: @JohnL. No way... I'll try to translate the task word by word from German: "For a language $A$, let $p(A)$ be the minimum pumping length of $A$ from the pumping lemma for regular languages. Show for any languages $A,B$ with finite minimum pumping lengths (not just regular $A,B$):

$p(AB)\leq p(A)+p(B)$ and there exist regular $A,B$ so that equality holds."

So is my homework task wrong or did I misunderstand something here?

Comment: this is a silly question... but wont the empty set work here? i.e $A=B=\emptyset$ and then $p(AB)=p(\emptyset)=0=0+0=p(A)+p(B)$?

Comment: The empty set **is** regular but it sounds too good to actually be the answer they look for

Comment: @nirshahar The pumping length can't actually be zero because one condition is that we can write all words $w\geq p$ as $w=xyz$ with $y\neq \epsilon$ ($\epsilon$ is the empty word). So the minimum pumping length of the empty set is 1.

Comment: there is no $w$ though so that still holds :o

Comment: @nirshahar That does make sense... I have to agree it's not very satisfying, but it seems to be a correct answer.

Comment: To expand on John L.'s hint, if we require that the pumping constant be at least $1$, then $p(AB) \leq p(A) + p(B) - 1$, essentially since if $x \in A$, $y \in B$, and $|xy| \geq p(A) + p(B) - 1$, then either $|x| \geq p(A)$ or $|y| \geq p(B)$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For a language $L$, denote $P(L)$ as the minimum pumping length of $L$. It is implied that $P(L)\ge1$.

**Proposition**. Let $A,B$ be two languages with finite minimum pumping lengths. We have $P(AB)\le P(A)+P(B)-1$. Moreover, there exist regular $A,B$ such that the equality holds.

**Proof**. Let $w=w_Aw_b\in AB$, where $w_A\in A, w_B\in B$. Assume $|w|\ge P(A)+P(B)-1$. Then either $|w_A|\ge P(A)$ or $|w_B|\ge P(B)$; otherwise, $$|w|=|w_A|+|w_B|\le P(A)-1 + P(B)-1\lt P(A)+P(B)-1,$$
which contradicts the assumption.

Now there are two cases.

- $|w_A|\ge P(A)$. Since $P(A)$ is a pumping length for $A$, $w_a\in A$ can be written as $w_a=xyz$, satisfying the following conditions:

  - $|y|\geq 1$
  - $|xy|\leq P(A)$
  - $\forall n\geq 0, xy^{n}z\in A$

  Hence, $w$ can be written as $w=xyz_B$, where $z_B=zw_B$, satisfying the following conditions:

  - $|y|\geq 1$
  - $|xy|\leq P(A) + P(B)-1$ (since $P(B)\ge1$)
  - $\forall n\geq 0, xy^{n}z_B=(xy^nz)w_B\in AB$.

  That is, $w$ can be pumped with pumping length $P(A)+P(B)-1$.
- $|w_B|\ge P(B)$. This case is similar to the case above.

Combining the two cases, we have proved $P(A)+P(B)-1$ is a pumping length for $AB$.

Let $A=\{\epsilon,\alpha, \alpha^2, \cdots, \alpha^{n-1}, \beta^n, \beta^{2n}, \beta^{3n}, \cdots, \}$, which is a regular language of minimal pumping length $n$.  Let $B=\{\epsilon,\alpha, \alpha^2, \cdots, \alpha^{m-1}, \beta^m, \beta^{2m}, \beta^{3m}, \cdots\}$, which is a regular language of minimal pumping length $m$. Since $\alpha^{n-1}\alpha^{m-1}$, which is a word in $AB$ of length $n+m-2$, cannot be pumped, $AB$ is a regular language of minimal pumping length $n+m-1$.

Comment: An even simpler tight example is $A = \{ a^n \}$, $B = \{ a^m \}$.

Comment: Yes, that is the simplest tight example. (I wanted to show the equality can hold even if $AB$ does contain a string for every length smaller than $n+m-1$, forestalling some potential attempts that could lead to $n+m$ as the minimal pumping length for some more restricted languages by excluding equality.)

Comment: It should have been defined that $P(L)=\infty$ if $L$ is not pumpable.

Comment: Thanks for the proof. This made me learn to try and prove that a statement to prove is in fact wrong if I get stuck so hard in the future. But actually, with the definition from my lecture, there is an edge case. The pumping length is defined to be greater than or equal to $0$ there, not to $1$. As @nirshahar said, in that case, the pumping length of the empty language is $0$. I think this incontinuity makes a good point on why defining the pumping length to be $\geq 1$ makes more sense.

Comment: @Keno Thanks for your feedback.  I agreed and agree. The empty language is such an extraordinary edge case that we could specify 0 as its minimal pumping length, although a pumping length is expected to be greater than 0 in general.

Comment: The proof above does not cover the empty language explicitly, although the proposition does hold if $P(\emptyset)=1$. (This comment will be deleted if the proof is updated to cover that case explicitly.)